How to disable file system check on Ubuntu 24.04
A couple months ago, my laptop suddenly stopped being able to hibernate or lock and then boot back up. For some reason I thought it was my 48 gigabytes of swap space (don't judge me please) that was messing it up. So, as a stupid person, I decided to just remove the swap space while the system was running. That didn't fix it and whenever I boot up since it takes ten minutes to run a file system check. (Edit: I did add back swap space) It says press ctrl+c to stop it but that doesn't work so I just wait for ten minutes. I tried a suggestion on a different forum which said I should add fsck.mode=skip to my boot options but this just disabled the message but it still takes a while to boot. I do not want to reinstall because it usually takes the whole day of copying my stuff.
Update:
I tried sudo apt update and then sudo apt upgrade because some people had this fix their problem but this did not work.
Update v2: I was scrolling through dmesg logs and I found the lines [    0.024192] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic root=UUID=7becc5d5-d0f7-49ee-85ad-6c80a1ef03ce ro quiet splash fsck.mode=skip vt.handoff=7 [    0.024263] Unknown kernel command line parameters "splash BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic", will be passed to user space. , suggesting that the fsck.mode=skip didn't actually work.
Update 3:
Fscking in the recovery menu shows fsck output
Update 4:
I have decided to start using Debian Linux because it has had much less issues than Ubuntu Linux. There is no need to answer this question anymore.

Did you remove the swap partition entry in /etc/fstab?

I don't remember @OrganicMarble I think I just used the disks software.

I think that 'disks' should have configured fstab properly, but if there is a swap entry still in /etc/fstab, that may be the problem.  Mine looks like this: UUID=48a73f88-fcd1-404c-aaa8-bcd8142b1448 none            swap    sw              0       0 Your UUID would be different.

I also did add the swap space back so it should be there.

Oh, I missed that part in your post. At any rate, I suggest you check fstab and make sure it points to the proper swap UUID.

It is there I see /dev/disk/by-uuid/ed750ad7-141f-4edf-8173-ee7c3f136372 none swap sw 0 0 also I forgot to mention that in post I will update it.

I am going to try sudo apt upgrade because some people have gotten it to stop by doing that.

Automatic fsck at boot time is an indication that your system is not properly shutting down or a physical disk problem. After fixing your swap problem and fully updating your system (apt update ; apt dist-upgrade), please concentrate on these problems too.

I usually properly power down my laptop but sometimes my friend and my brother close the lid to mess with me (which usually stops it from normally shutting down). Also I do not want to run the apt dist-upgrade command because it says it is freeing space and the only other time I have seen that is when the fuse package has messed up my grub install. Also I am not sure if the swap thing is really fixed. Also I got my laptop about a year and a half ago so the ssd shouldn't be failing.

If you remove a partition and add it back, its UUID is going to change. It's not as if nothing happened. I don't know if you followed @OrganicMarble 's suggestion to verify that the UUID listed in /etc/fstab actually pointed to the right partition (and that there were no leftovers left from the previous swap partition still in place), however I'm also under the impression that fixing fstab would've likely also fixed your issue. I'm sorry to say, switching to Debian won't prevent this kind of issues, at all, to avoid these kind of issues you should probably switch OS (i.e. not Linux)entirely.

This kind of thing has never happened to me on Debian Linux and I don't need to worry as much about killing my grub installation from installing something.
